# What happens when calling a blocking function from ISR in VxWorks

Tags: vxworks

What happens when a blocking function from ISR in VxWorks, for example, `msgQsend` was called from an ISR and the `msgQ` buffer was full (assuming that `msgQsend` was called with `WAIT_FOREVER`)?

**Note:** I'm assuming it will fail in the scheduler. If this is the case, how does the VxWorks scheduler know that it was called from an ISR?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple questions here, I will answer them in reverse order:

> how does the VxWorks scheduler know that it was called from an ISR?

It uses intContext() from intLib():

```
BOOL intContext (void)
DESCRIPTION

This routine returns TRUE only if the current execution
state is in interrupt context and not in a meaningful task context.
```

Next question:

> What happens when a blocking function from ISR in VxWorks

VxWorks checks if you try to call a blocking function at the interrupt level, and it will return ERROR when you do.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `msgQSend` from an ISR, the timeout value must be 0.  If you attempt to use it with another value, an error is returned and the errno is set to `S_msgQLib_NON_ZERO_TIMEOUT_AT_INT_LEVEL`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about older and newer versions, but I can tell you by personal experience that in VxWorks 6.x calling a blocking function from an ISR in x86 architectures results in an immediate reboot or a severe system hang depending on the settings of your BSP.

You can see by yourself anyway, just try it!

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply try it? Create a full msgQ, generate the interrupt and try to put a message into the queue...

My guess is that the hole system will hang since (on many systems) ISRs have to complete before another interrupt may be processed... But this very much depends on the system you're running on.

And remember: in an ISR you're "outside" of the operating system!